# Vectorizing a pareto front algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

First of all, here's my setup:

- `x` is an `n x 1` vector containing the values of a first cost function.
- `y` is another `n x 1` vector containing the values of a second cost function.
- `a` is an `m x 1` vector containing the indices of `x` and `y` to be checked, this is used to selectively exclude values from the algorithm. Unless needed, this can be replaced with `1:n`.
- It's safe to assume all combinations `(x,y)` are unique.

The task is to find the pareto optimal set of value pairs `(x,y)`, that is, all pairs that are not dominated. A pair is called dominated if there exists another pair `(u,v)` such that `u <= x && v <= y` and one of these comparisons is strict: `u < x || v < y`. In other words, a pair is dominated if another pair is better in one value and not worse in the other.

My research up to this point has yielded three working algorithms, that are unfortunately all reliant on loops. Here's how they work and what time I got for running them with `x`, `y` and `a` of length `1e8`:

> 1. Sort `x` in ascending order. Add the first pair to the pareto set.
> 2. Loop through `x`. Add each pair to the pareto set where `y` is lower than the previous pareto pair's `y`.
>
> Elapsed time is 80.204052 seconds.

> 1. Find `min(x)`. Add that pair to the pareto set.
> 2. Select all pairs where `y` is lower than the previously added pair's `y`.
> 3. Go to step 1 unless step 2 resulted in the empty set.
>
> Elapsed time is 2.993350 seconds.

> 1. Loop through all pairs `(x,y)`.
> 2. Remove all pairs `(u,v)` with `x >= u && y >= v`.
>
> Elapsed time is 105.924814 seconds.

Now what I'm attempting to do is create a vectorized algorithm. It doesn't have to be based on one of the above, but I wasn't able to find any other working algorithm. The best I could do is this:

```
ap = a(y < min(y(x == min(x))) | x < min(x(y == min(y))));
```

which does usually find all pareto optimal pairs, but includes all pairs not dominated by the pair at `min(x)` or `min(y)`, even if one dominates another. I say usually because it fails entirely if there is only one globally optimal pair that dominates every other pair. Replacing the `<` with `<=` cures the second problem, but finds even more dominated pairs (those that have only one worse value). I also ran this through the same timer as above:

> Elapsed time is 0.800385 seconds.

---

Here's a test script I'm using to check how the algorithm does, feel free to use it

```
for i=1:25
    x = randi(8,10,1);
    y = randi(8,10,1);
    a = 1:10;
    ap = a(y < min(y(x == min(x))) | x < min(x(y == min(y)))); %// algorithm here
    figure(1);
    subplot(5,5,i);
    plot(a,x,'b',a,y,'r',ap,x(ap),'b.',ap,y(ap),'r.','MarkerSize',20);
    axis([0,11,0,9]);
    set(gca,'XGrid','on','YGrid','on','XTick',1:10,'YTick',0:8);
    figure(2);
    subplot(5,5,i);
    plot(x,y,'b.',x(ap),y(ap),'ro','MarkerSize',10);
    axis([0,9,0,9]);
end
```

Comment: I always used [**`this function from File Exchange`**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17251-pareto-front) it was really fast for thousands of points, so you could sneak in and look how they have done it. (Use and cite!)

Comment: @thewaywewalk I found this as well, but unless I'm missing something, this is only a compiled mex file and there's no way for me to see the actual source code and figure out what it does. I'm not comfortable with using an external source I don't understand...

Comment: okay you're right, I haven't checked that before. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So, if speed is the primary characteristic (after correctness), then I found a recursive version of the faster loop version to be over 30% faster:

```
>> testPareto(1e8);
Recursive:
Elapsed time is 4.507267 seconds.
Loop:
Elapsed time is 6.136856 seconds.
Vector:
Elapsed time is 7.246806 seconds.
```

Again, the time depends on the machine and it might even depend on matlab's version. Here is the code:

```
function testPareto(dim)

x = rand(dim, 1);
y = rand(dim, 1);

tic;
rR = paretoRecursive(x, y);
disp('Recursive:');
toc;

tic;
rL = paretoLoop(x, y);
disp('Loop:');
toc;

tic;
rV = paretoVector(x, y);
disp('Vector:');
toc;

end

function result = paretoLoop(x, y)
    result = zeros(numel(x), 2);
    off = 1;
    loop = true;
    while loop
        xmin = min(x);
        ymin = min(y(x == xmin));
        yfilter = y < ymin;
        result(off, :) = [xmin ymin];
        off = off + 1;
        if any(yfilter)
            x = x(yfilter);
            y = y(yfilter);
        else
            loop = false;
            result(off:end, :) = [];
        end
    end
end

function result = paretoRecursive(x, y)
    xmin = min(x);
    ymin = min(y(x == xmin));
    yfilter = y < ymin;
    if any(yfilter)
        result = [xmin ymin; paretoRecursive(x(yfilter), y(yfilter))];
    else
        result = [xmin ymin];
    end
end

function result = paretoVector(x, y)
    xmin = min(x);
    xfilter = x == xmin;
    ymin = min(y(xfilter));
    yfilter = y < ymin;
    if any(yfilter)
        [x, ind] = sort(x(yfilter));
        y = y(yfilter);
        y = y(ind);
        yfilter = [true; y(2:end) < cummin(y(1:end-1))];
        result = [xmin x(yfilter)'; ymin y(yfilter)']';
    else
        result = [xmin ymin];
    end
end
```

Comment: The time is what matters, though. The example I gave is the only vectorized approximation I managed to build and the time benchmark is a guideline for what I'm looking for. The best looped solution that actually works (note how I'm saying in the question that the vectorized approximation doesn't actually work/perform the task sufficiently) still takes 4 times as long as the (not working) vectorized approximation. Please take the time to run the benchmark as that is what validates your answer in this case.

Comment: I would disagree. I would suggest that giving the right result matters more than time. But no problem, I will run it shortly, but for the previous results it is not clear to me what was the input: randi(8,1e8,1)? Or rand(1e8, 1)?

Comment: I just realized that my answer has serious problems when dealing with integers, as they can very easily be duplicates, while for doubles this would be less of an issue, I suppose. Although if duplicates are not an issue, then the slow unique can be dropped and turned into a sort. By the way, with 1e8 random doubles, it takes about 10 seconds without unique. However, the overwhelming majority of that time is spent on the sort, so I am trying to see how to circumvent it.

Comment: Well, I do have a (looped) algorithm that does provide correct results in 3 seconds, so giving the right results doesn't matter unless it's faster. That's the intent of the question, I'm not looking for a vectorized algorithm for the sake of it, but because they're usually faster.

Comment: I found a recursive version that was faster. I also tried to improve on it by making each level of the recursion filter out more elements. First by finding the smallest y to the remaining pairs and doing the same logic as done before for x. Also, to combine them into complex numbers, x +i*y, and filter out also those with higher phase than the first identified pair, as the method finds pair that are monotonic decreasing in the phase. In both cases the performance of the recursive method suffered, at least for high sample. I didn't try it for smaller samples.